# Keep TCP socket client after send a message to socket server

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am implementing a socket node server using the [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net) library and WebSockets at the browser. I am using telnet `host` `port` successfully, but the browser works incorrectly. The Browser connects successfully to the socket server and sends a message. My server implements a `data` event and triggers `close` and  `end` events immediately. `close` , `end` events excute remove client when they disconnect ( turn off brower, loose connection ...).

I don't want the browser to send a message and then loose the connection. 
Does anyone know what is the problem?

**Socket server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');
var config = require(path.join(__dirname, '/config.json'));
var net = require('net');
app.use(cors());

var serverSocket = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Connected socket server\r\n');
});

serverSocket.listen(3332, () => {
    console.log('opened socket on', serverSocket.address());
});

var client = [];
serverSocket.on('connection', (conn) => {
    console.log('client ', client.length, ' connected');

    conn.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    while (client.indexOf(conn) !== -1) {
        // socket id exits
        conn.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        console.log('repeat');
    }
    client.push(conn);
    console.log('client id ', conn.id);
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
    });

    conn.on('end', function() {
        // client.splice(client.indexOf(conn), 1);
        // console.log(conn.id + ' disconnected');
        // console.log('clientArr ' + client);
    });

    conn.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log("Caught flash policy server socket error: ");
        console.log(err.stack);
    });

    conn.on('close', (e) => {
        client.splice(client.indexOf(conn), 1);
        console.log(conn.id + ' disconnected');
        console.log('clientArr ' + client);
    });

});

app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Server start on port: ' + config.port);
```

**Client ( Browser)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>test</head>
<body>
<div class="">
    <button>button</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create WebSocket connection.
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.111:3332');

    // Connection opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
        socket.send('Hello Server!');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output when browser connect to server

```
Server start on port: 6010
opened socket on { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 3332 }
connecting mongoose
client  0  connected
client id  685
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.111:3332
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:8643
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: vi,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
Sec-WebSocket-Key: lNMRkgoSb8xOH5iuE/f4UA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits


685 disconnected
clientArr
```

Server can't log `Hello Server` from client instead of header something also server loss client's send message immediately.. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket connections work through a well-known protocol, documented in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). Your server doesn't implement this protocol, it's just a regular TCP server.

When the browser makes the WebSocket connection to your server, and your server doesn't respond according to the protocol, the browser closes the connection (probably with a protocol error message being logged to console).

To implement a WebSocket server, take a look at the [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package.

Comment: I want to create a socket tcp regular ( no request special ). I used to use socket io, but socket io just only communicate between socket io and socket io client. How to create a socket tcp regular in browser .?

Comment: @Ntlzz93 that's not possible.